# SQL to update a column using the data in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax

Using SQL Server, I would like to know the syntax needed to update a column `code` in a table with the first x characters of another column `customer` and then a serial number.

So I have a table holding customer records. Eg smith holdings, smiths limited, smith and sons. Etc…. I want to the populate another column (`code`) in that table (`customers`) with the first three characters of the customer plus a serial number. So the three rows would then have and new column that have and column set to SMI001 the next row column would have a new entry in the field SMI002 ETC…. SMI003 and so on.

See example below. Any help would be appreciated.

```
customer                      code
----------------------------------------
Smith partners limited        SMI001
Smith and sons                SMI002
Smith plc                     SMI003
Smith and Co                  SMI004
```

SQL code:

```
UPDATE customers 
SET code = customer + 001
```

Comment: What are you going to do for 1000? Honestly this seems like a bad idea as it violates 1NF by shoving two values into a single tuple.  But if you really want to go ahead with this then you need to use the LEFT and RIGHT string functions. You will also likely need to use ROW_NUMBER

Comment: Also not good for company without three characters .. think Musk's `X` formerly known as `Twitter` ... if you have a choice, there's no real advantage here vs just 1,2,3 ... as company ids (and some disadvantages).

Comment: Does your numbering need to restart for every first three characters? What would something like "Joe's Bakery' be? And what about characters that are not a-z? Spaces, quotes etc.

Comment: The serial number will only need to be invoked if the first three digits are identical. I missed that sorry. 
So if smuck limited we’re present then the field would = smu001 joes bakery would be JOE001 there’s no records that have any special characters and the likely hood of them ever being the case is extremely unlikely.

Comment: Well like I said before this seems like a poor design choice. But the solution is using LEFT, RIGHT and ROW_NUMBER.

Comment: Thanks appreciate your comments I will look into how to use the left, right  and row_number features before I make a decision however I will head your comments and take a look to see if I can approach it another ways.

Comment: Let's say you succeed in your task. But then someone else adds a Smith & Wesson customer. You need to think about how to maintain this "code" thing, same issue if people are changing the names. Usually you dont' wanna sit around doing manual updates

Comment: What if the customer changes? do you need to refresh the code value as well? If that's the case, you'll need to define a computed column.

Comment: No if the customer name changes we keep the same code.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   customer VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL  
  
);
INSERT INTO mytable
(customer ) VALUES 
('Smith partners limited'),
('Smith and sons'),
('Smith plc'),
('Smith and Co');
```

adding column

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
ADD code VARCHAR(100);
```

using `With` in `Update` and string function `Left` to get first three left characters, `Upper` to capitalize characters, `Concat` to add `00` to string and `Row_number` to produce `1,2,3`

```
with t as (
select customer,code,concat(upper(left(customer,3))
  ,'00',
row_number() over (order by (select null))) code1
 from mytable
)

update t
set code=code1
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pyjOYhRy)

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply, I'll give this ago as it looks exactly what I am looking for. Thanks once again.

Comment: There are some cons of using this approach: between the insert and the update you are keeping your column value as NULL, that means any process trying to read from that table might get inconsistent data. Second, since you want to assign a value to that column as soon as you insert the customer, a better approach would be to use a PERSISTED CALCULATED COLUMN or a TRIGGER ON INSERT (if you don't need to update the code once created) because it works in the same insert transaction

Answer (score 0):

If you store a subindex in the table future updates will be easier, and actual code can be computed (optionally persisted).

Storing the prefix data (SMI) improves clarity. Populating it manually would allow the prefix to be redefined at some future point if necessary. Alternatively, computing it automatically saves code, and we can persist it to save computation and [allow indexing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-computed-column-definition-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#persisted).

Using the latter option:

```
DECLARE @mytable TABLE (
    customer VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
    prefix AS UPPER(LEFT(customer,3)) PERSISTED, 
    subindex INT NULL, 
    code AS UPPER(LEFT(customer,3)) + RIGHT('00' + CAST(subindex AS VARCHAR(3)), 3) PERSISTED
    );

-- Initial data
INSERT INTO @mytable (customer, subindex)
VALUES 
    ('Smith partners limited', 1),
    ('Smith and sons', 2),
    ('Smith plc', 3),
    ('Smith and Co', 4);

SELECT * FROM @mytable;

-- New customer
INSERT INTO @mytable (customer )
VALUES 
    ('Smith and Jones');

SELECT * FROM @mytable;

-- Allocate new subindex values
WITH d
AS
(
SELECT prefix, MAX(subindex) AS max_subindex
FROM @mytable
GROUP BY prefix
)
UPDATE m
SET subindex = COALESCE(max_subindex, 0) + rn
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY code ORDER BY subindex) AS rn
    FROM @mytable
    ) m
    INNER JOIN d
       ON d.prefix = m.prefix
WHERE subindex IS NULL;

SELECT * FROM @mytable;
GO
```

NB:

- Messy code for calculating `code` needed to pad subindex with leading zeroes
- `COALESCE` needed in case there are no rows with that `prefix`

With an actual table, you could have an index on prefix and subindex to help allocate new indexes.

Same issues re. the window where the code is `NULL` as for RF1991's answer, as flagged by Marco. Whether it's managed in a trigger or other code will depend how your updates occur. I don't think it can just be calculated as the subindex needs allocating based on the prefix.